# How to add Markdown-it to angular 8

Tags: angular, markdown-it

I wonder if anyone knows how to add [Markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) to an existing Angular 8 application. I have installed the package with `npm install` but don't know how to import it into my component.
Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install markdown-it

```
npm i markdown-it
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import md from 'markdown-it';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  private markdown;
  outHtml;
  constructor(){
    this.markdown=md();
    this.outHtml=this.markdown.render("# Ahmad Hamzavi");
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

```html
<span [innerHTML]="outHtml" ></span>
```